# Use `requestAnimationFrame` in redux for multiple components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building a web application for paper trading, so i have a lot of charts that rendered using canvas, and these components basically takes a same state `time` from my redux store so that they can render based on data between `time - 1day` and say `time`

I sort of understand how `requestAnimationFrame` works, but not sure if I could just treat `time` as a normal redux state, have `requestAnimationFrame` to dispatch action to increment it, and different components will just repaint properly?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    loop(time) {
        store.dispatch({
            type: TICK,
            timeDelta = time - this.lastTime;
        });
        this.lastTime = time;
        this.id = requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.lastTime = 0;
        requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
    }

    componentDidMount(){
         cancelAnimationFrame(this.id);
    }
}

const timeReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case TICK:
            return {...state, currentTime: currentTime + action.timeDelta }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data : state.data.slice(state.currentTime - 1d, state.currentTime)
});

const Chart = ({data}) => {
    // this.canvas draws based on data prop
}

const ChartContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Chart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your assessment is correct. You should be treating "now" as a snapshot of time in your store so that other components have a single source of truth to render based on.

The alternative approach is using the *actual* time in your components. The problem with this is that there is no way for the components to synchronize and confirm that they are all using the same time. Redux takes care of this for you, as each component will listen for tick dispatches and update accordingly.

Make sure that you get the time *once*, in one line of code, for all of your components. Once you know the time according to your application, then you should tell everything about it via `dispatch`.

You also want to make sure you have impure functions (such as "Get me the current timestamp") in your action creators and not your reducers.

Comment: thanks @Dykotomee, my plan is to use the `time` that `requestAnimationFrame` passed into the callback `loop` , and then pass that time in the action